# App crashes on if statement

Tags: java, android

I want to create a randomizer app but every time i click on the button the app crashes 
here is the code for the MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView random_number_text_view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        random_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random_number_text_view);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(5 - 1) +1;

        if (randomNumber == 1){
            random_number_text_view.setText(randomNumber);
        } else {
            random_number_text_view.setText(randomNumber);
        }
    }

}
```

i appreciate your answers

Dan

Comment: Show the LogCat please.

Comment: `random_number_text_view.setText(""+randomNumber);`

Comment: id `random_number_text_view` does not exists

Comment: Also your code will not compile: `TextView random_number_text_view;` and `random_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random_number);`

should be

`random_number_text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random_number);`

and once you get that compiling, `TextView.setText` takes a charSequence or a string resource id.

If you pass an integer, like randomNumber, then it will assume it's a string resource ID, and you'll get the ResourceNotFoundException as Blackbelt has marked. You should use `random_number_text_view.setText(String.valueOf(randomNumber))`

Comment: Well, id `random_number_text_view` does not even exists... so it's not the reason of `ResourceNotFoundException ` . OP code might throw a NPE if it can compile

Comment: true sorry, I just looked at the field usage. Thanks, updated

Comment: @hacketo, it shouldn't have compiled. But after it's fixed, there'll be a ResourceNotFoundException when you try to use `setText(randomNumber)` where randomNumber is an integer.

Comment: NPE might happens before, because of the id `random_number_text_view ` that does not exists, so can't do `random_number_text_view.setText` on `null` . The `ResourceNotFoundException ` flagged as duplicate might not be the real reason.

Comment: Yes, my comment assumes that the `findViewById` is fixed as per my answer.